# Quick RSYNC code correction

Tags: rsync

What's wrong with this code?

> sudo -u replicant rsync -av -e "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i /home/replicant/.ssh/id_rsa" --exclude 'media/' --exclude 'var/' --exclude '.svn' root@$ADMIN:/var/www/ /var/www/ &> /tmp/rsync
>    if
>  [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
>       echo "`date`: Error rsync'ing code base from $ADMIN check /tmp/rsync" | mail -s "Rsync error!" $DEVEMAIL
>   echo "`date`: Error rsync'ing code base from $ADMIN check /tmp/rsync" >> $LOGFILE
>   echo "root@$ADMIN:/var/www /var/www" >> $LOGFILE
>   exit 
>   fi

I keep getting this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605)
>   [Receiver=3.0.9]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Late reply, but it sounds like your SSH key was not accepted by the remote server, check it's the right public key and that it's readable by the replicant user

Answer (score 0):

Try to login directly on SSH to fix your issues, then move on to your rsync test. So start with:

`ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i /home/replicant/.ssh/id_rsa root@$ADMIN`

**Sidenotes:**

- don't use `root` for such a task
- add `set -eu` at the start of your Bash script, so that errors will end up your script and ease debugging (for example if `$ADMIN` is not defined, the script will end in error)